# React-Router-Dom nested paths mixing with server requests

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, react-router-dom, koa2

I'm using Redux-Saga and when I send requests to the Koa server e.g. `yield call(fetch, "/v1/user/${action.id}", options)` the React-Router-Dom path of the Component with the `PUT` form (`<Route exact path="/dashbourd/usersettings" component={user_settings} />`) gets all mixed up with the second parameter in call, the console shows this `PUT /dashboard/usersettings/{id}` instead of `PUT /v1/user/{id}`. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path of the request URI when calling fetch?

Comment: Yes, localhost:4000/v1/users/${action.id} but when I do that, the app acts like there is no such endpoint.

Comment: How did you specify put in your options. Can you show your total code?

Comment: It's just a usual server request. I can't show the code sorry but if you try to use any CRUD keyword with a nested Component then this error happens.